# LDAP read privileges for comupter, IIS under ApplicationPoolIdentity user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, iis-7.5, application-pools

Is it possible to set up LDAP read privileges to Active Directory for computer account?

If I run web application on IIS 7.5, which application pool is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity, I have read that in such case IIS is accessing network resources under computer account.

So, I want to keep ApplicationPool running under ApplicationPoolIdentity, but want to be able to read LDAP data by default without using any other LDAP user in application. Is it possible?